# Blank screen when mstsc /admin to Windows Server 2003 EE

Tags: windows-server-2003, rdp

Previously I had no issues with connecting to the console session on Windows Server 2003, but today for some reason I get blank screen after I enter username, password and press Enter. There's simply desktop background visible.

If I try to connect with the same account without **/admin** switch - it works just fine.
Have tried to use another account - same issue.

**Remote host OS:** W2k3 EE.

Already tried to disable **Bitmap Caching** from the **Experience** tab - didn't work.
I also tried to connect from another host - no luck.
Deleting domain user profile on problem host had no positive effect.

Server has not been restarted yet, since this is production one.
No error/warning windows pop up after entering credentials.

Any ideas why it doesn't work with /admin switch and works fine without?

Comment: Reboot fixed an issue :).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to press CTRL+ALT+ESC to get a Task Manager, File > Run, explorer.exe to try to manually kick off the desktop. I've done that before.

Comment: Yep, I thought about this, but the thing is that I need firstly to connect to gateway server and once connected I can then reach that particular server. Playing with rdp client options to send CTRL+ALT+ESC(DEL) directly to the problem server didn't work, since had not much time. Will give it a show tomorrow once again.